# How RGB cones see other frequencies?

Tags: human-eye

Orange,violet and yellow have different frequencies.
How can we see them, as we have only three receptors rgb?

Merely combining those frequencies cannot generate a new one.

Comment: This question has rather [detailed answers in the physics community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425649/247642). In a nutshell - they don't see other frequencies, but rather the color is determined by our brain by the relative excitation of different cones.

Comment: How does your compute display create all sorts of colors when it has only 3 colors of pixels?